# Can you push / pull between two identical repositories with EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, dvcs, egit

I've got a repository A that I would like to copy to create B.
Then I'd like to be able to pull A->B, do some merging, then push B->A.

Is this possible with EGit?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add and configure the Remotes. http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Remote_Repositories